# putting elements into a list of strings

Tags: java, string

I need to insert some data into a Map that expects a String as the key and a List of Strings as the value, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is what I've tried to do.

First of all, I've created a HashMap, then I've created a new object, and now there's the problem.

I create a new List of Strings giving it a name, then I think that I have to use the "put" method, but it's wrong, as I have an error that tells: "The method put(String, List) in the type HashMap> is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean)".

Why a boolean? When I type .put() in Eclipse, it tells me that it expects that the parameter is a "List  value", ok, but how do I write that? Can you better explain me the problem? Thanks.

```
 public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         HashMap<String, List<String>> dizionarioMultilingua;
         dizionarioMultilingua = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

         List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

         dizionarioMultilingua.put("dds", list.add(""));

     }
 }
```

Comment: list.add() returns boolean. You can do dizionarioMultilingua.put("string", new ArrayList<>()); And after than you can do dizionarioMultilingua.get("string").add(something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small mistake in your code. Since the put method require an String and a list, you should supply the list as the 2nd parameter. Not, **list.add("")**. List.add() return a boolean stating whether the element we specified was successfully added to the list.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     HashMap<String, List<String>> dizionarioMultilingua;
     dizionarioMultilingua = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

     List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
     list.add("");
     dizionarioMultilingua.put("dds", list);

 }
```

Comment: Got it! So does it mean that if I have ten different Strings, I have to create ten different Lists?

Comment: Nope. Since you are using a List of Strings, you can add multiple strings in one list. For example, list.add("item 1"); list.add("item 2");.....;list.add("item n"); and then call dizionarioMultilingua.put("dds", list); to add the list to the hashmap. Also you can use multiple lists as well and add then under different keys in the hashmap.

Comment: Ah ok, I've explained it wrong. Let's say I have "dds", "asd" and "xyz", and for dds i have n list.add(something), for asd other list elements, etc...do I have to create a list for every "put() first parameter"? If it's a multilanguage vocabulary, it's impossible to create a list for each "word" (for each first parameter of put(), that represent a word)

Comment: in that case, if you want to keep distinct lists of strings under each key then you have to write a mechanism to generate the list for each key. The simplest way will be using a loop. But that depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

[ArrayList#add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) returns boolean, so it appears like you are putting `<String,Boolean>`, while expected is `<String, List<String>>`

what you have to do , is filling the Strings list first, then put it in the map

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("item1")
list.add("item2")
list.add("item3")
dizionarioMultilingua.put("dds", list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, [list.add(E e)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) returns a boolean value.

Firstly, you need to prepare your list by inserting multiple(or as many as you desire) String items to the list).

Then, at the last step, you should map that with the string.

Comment: No code was provided for what you were stating above. Although, strictly speaking, being correct information, it wasn't going to be especially helpful to the OP in this instance, compared to everyone else's responses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `dizionarioMultilingua.put("dds", list.add(""));`
This is because `list.add("")` returns boolean that indicates if element was succesfully added to list.

If you want to put your list into HashMap then firstly you should fill your list and then put it in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add strings to your list before "putting" it in the Map.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("");

dizionarioMultilingua.put("dds", list);
```

The call to "list" vs. "list.add("")" are very different in the sense that the first refers to the object List, while the second is just a method call that will return a Boolean.